# Spark Scala: value add is not a member of scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is my code, trying to add a data frame row to a list, then return it in a tuple.

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

```
myDF.rdd.filter{row:Row => row.getString(6).length > 0}.map {
  row: Row => 
  var rowList: ListBuffer[Row] = ListBuffer()
  rowList.add(row)
  (row.getString(1) + "_" + row.getString(2) + "_" + row.getString(6) + "_" + row.getString(7) + "_" + row.getString(14), rowList)
}.count()
```

Then I got the following error:

```
 error: value add is not a member of scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
                rowList.add(row)
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add is not the standard ListBuffer API. Just need to import the following line:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

Answer (score 3):

use += in ListBuffer: rowList += row